# IIS 6.1 File Upload Limit

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-6, upload

Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter IIS 6.1

We're experiencing issues trying to upload a file larger than 1.5mb on our PHP web application.  PHP upload limit is set to 20mb and verified.

I've been looking for solutions but none of them exist on this particular version of Windows and IIS 6.1, eg; like modifying the 'metabase.xml' file (it cannot be found on the server).  Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Comment: What 'issues' are you experiencing?  What happens when it fails?  Error message?

Comment: Issue: PHP doesn't get a file from IIS Error: Error - File Too Big

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking perhaps you're running into a time-out issue waiting for the upload to finish, and not really a size limitation.

Here's some info from the PHP folks that may be candidates for checking:

"[max_execution_time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)" **integer**

This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly written scripts from tying up the server. The default setting is 30. When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.

The maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream operations etc. Please see the "[set_time_limit()](https://www.php.net/set_time_limit)" function for more details.

*Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also interrupt PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a CGI timeout function. Both default to 300 seconds.* See your web server documentation for specific details.

"[max_input_time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)" **integer**

This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse input data, like POST, GET and *file uploads*.

Note: The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. **This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real**.

Additionally [here's some info on checking/setting CGI Timeout in IIS5 and 6](http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=7).

HTH

Comment: It's an Intranet application so there are no timeout issues as the next page is instant.

Comment: I'll point back to my comment on your original question -- "What 'issues' are you experiencing? What happens when it fails? Error message?"

Comment: Issue: PHP doesn't get a file from IIS
Error: Error - File Too Big

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176484/open-source-file-upload-with-no-timeout-on-iis6-with-asp-asp-net-2-0-or-php5

Comment: Thanks for the link but it's not a timeout issue, it's a file size issue.